# Which codec is used for online video Streaming?

Tags: webrtc, opus, vp8

I am using WebRTC with kurento media server, as far as i came to know WebRTC supports VP8 for video Streaming and using opus for audio Streaming, So my question is if i want to compress the stream which includes both audio and video, so do i need to use both(VP8 and opus)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are streaming both audio and video then it will use both an audio codec (typically Opus) and a video codec (typically VP8, VP9, or H.264).